# Appcelerator ArrowDB Cloud.Emails.send not sending emails

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, arrowdb

I have successfully setup the SMTP. When SMTP is setup I did receive an email with subject "[AMPLIFY Platform] Mobile Backend Services SMTP Test"

Then I have called Cloud.Emails.send with valid recipient email address. API call also return below response:
{"success":true,"error":false,"meta":{"status":"ok","code":200,"method_name":"emailFromTemplate"}}
But I do not receive any email. I am testing in "Development" environment.

Anyone have this issue with Appcelerator ArrowDB Emails.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the issue. It seems that Gmail was blocking emails. Initially, I setup SMTP by enabling "less secure apps access your account". Also allows access to security check prompts too. But wasn't receiving any emails and Appcelerator return success response.
Then I have created App password and used it in SMTP. Now everything works fine. App password should be the correct way to use Gmail SMTP.